# Where do I insert this section of code?

Tags: php, duplicates

I am very new to PHP. The code below has been cobbled together from numerous tutorials I have found online and it is working how I would like. I have had an email from my tutor requesting that we add code that would prevent duplicate email addresses being entered. I have the code that needs to be added but I do not have a clue where it should go.

Here is the existing code:

```
<?
include('config.php');

// table name 
$tbl_name=temp_members;

// Random confirmation code 
$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));

// values sent from form 
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$firstname=$_POST['firstName'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastName'];

// Insert data into database 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(confirm_code, email, password, firstname,     lastname)VALUES('$confirm_code', '$email', '$password', '$firstname', '$lastname')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);



// if suceesfully inserted data into database, send confirmation link to email 
if($result){

// ---------------- SEND MAIL FORM ----------------

// send e-mail to ...
$to=$email;

// Your subject
$subject="Francis Flower confirmation link";

// From
$headers="from: Francis Flower Admin <francis.flower.contact@gmail.com>";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

// Your message
$message = '<html><head>';
$message .= '<style type="text/css">
                        body {
                            font-family: Helvetica,         Arial;
                        }
                        .center {
                            text-align: left;
                        }
                        </style>';
$message .= '<body><div class="center"><img src="http://www.jblanksby.yourwebsolution.net/images/logo.png"/>';
$message .= "<p>Dear " .$_POST['firstName']. "&nbsp;" .$_POST['lastName'].", </p>";
$message .= '<p>Thank you for signing up for an account at Francis Flower. </p>';
$message .= '<p>Your new account details are below: </p>';
$message .= "<p>Email Address: ".$_POST['email']. "</p>";
$message .= "<p>Password: " .$_POST['password']. "</p>";
$message .= "<p>Before you can login, you need to activate your account using the link below:</p>";
$message .= "<p>Click on this link to activate your account</p>";
$message .= "<p>http://jblanksby.yourwebsolution.net/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code</p>";
$message .= '</div></body></html>';

// send email
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

}

// if not found 
else {
echo "Not found your email in our database";
}

// if your email succesfully sent
if($sentmail){ ?>
echo "Mail has been sent";
} else { 
echo "Mail has not been sent"}; 
?>
```

And here is the code the captures duplicate emails that I would like included in the above code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email = '{$email}'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if ( mysql_num_rows ( $result ) > 1 )
{
    /* Username already exists */
    echo 'Username already exists';
}
else
{
    /* Username doesn't exist */
    /* .. insert query */
}
```

Any assistant with this would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be placed right before you do the `INSERT` statement.

Note that your script is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack. At a minimum, call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on your `$_POST` input values:

```
// Get email from the form before checking if it was already inserted
// you don't need the other form values yet...
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email = '{$email}'";
$result_eml = mysql_query($query);

// Added some error checking here to make sure the query succeeded
// Also here, check for > 0, not > 1 -- you want to find out if 1 or more rows exist, not that 2 or more exist...
if ( $result_eml && mysql_num_rows ( $result_eml ) > 0 )
{
    /* Username already exists */
    echo 'Username already exists';
}
else if (!$result) {
   // error in query
}
else
{

  // table name 
  $tbl_name=temp_members;

  // Random confirmation code 
  $confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));

  // Other values sent from form 
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
  $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstName']);
  $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastName']);

  // Insert data into database 
  $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(confirm_code, email, password, firstname,     lastname)VALUES('$confirm_code', '$email', '$password', '$firstname', '$lastname')";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);

  // etc....

}
```

I'm not certain if this for an assignment or for production code, but I will add that it is a very bad idea to send a user's password via email.  Email is basically like a postcard -- unless you send it with encryption (which almost no one on earth does these days), it can be read by any server admin anywhere along its network path from sending point to receiving point.

Comment: It is for an assignment and our tutor wants us to send all account details via email and has explained exactly what you have said above. But thank you for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you could do.  You could put a unquie key on the database that would give you a mysql error on inserting a duplicate row.

You could also, check the database before you do an insert with the current data to make sure there were not any rows returned before you made the insert.

Those are just a few ideas that you could use.

also, check out [using PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)